# How to correctly throw an UnauthenticatedException in Cakephp 4?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm using the plugin Authentication 2 in cakephp 4.

I would like to throw an `UnauthenticatedException` when a user is not logged in and in the case of ajax request.
**The goal is to catch the exception in JSON.**

Here is my code from server :

```php
// in src/Controller/Admin/AdminController.php
use Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthenticatedException;

class AdminController extends AppController {

    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
    }

    public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        // The server receives an ajax request and the user is not logged in (any more), an UnauthenticatedException is thrown
        if ($this->request->is('ajax') && $this->request->getAttribute('identity') === null) {
            throw new UnauthenticatedException('Please log in');
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my code from client :

```js
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json';
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    // [...]
})
// [...]
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON); // There's no responseJSON in jqXHR...
    alert("(" + errorThrown + ")" + jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
    if (errorThrown == 'Unauthenticated') {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

The problem is that there's no `responseJSON` in `jqXHR`.

**Why is any other Exception (e.g `UnauthorizedException` that I used before) generating `responseJSON` in the return and not `UnauthenticatedException` ?**

How to do to make it work with `UnauthenticatedException` ?

Comment: Check what exactly the response is (use for example the browser's network console)... I guess it's a redirect, which would mean that you have configured the middleware's `unauthenticatedRedirect` option.

Comment: @ndm you're right, it seems to be a redirection and I have `'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url('/admin/users/login'),` in `Application.php`... How can I do to make it work like a regular exception like `UnauthorizedException` for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication middleware by default re-throws unauthenticated exceptions, that is unless you configure the `unauthenticatedRedirect` option, in that case it will transform those exceptions into redirects accordingly.

If you need to support both HTML and JSON requests/responses, then you can for example dynamically configure, respectively *not* configure the `unauthenticatedRedirect` option, based on the current request, eg in your `Application::getAuthenticationService()` method do something along the lines of:

```php
$service = new AuthenticationService();

$accepts = array_map('trim', explode(',', $request->getHeaderLine('Accept')));
$isJsonRequest = in_array('application/json', $accepts, true);

if (!$isJsonRequest) {
    // service config for non-JSON requests
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => /* ...*/,
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
}
```

Alternatively to evaluating the header manually, require the `request` to be an instance of `\Cake\Http\ServerRequest` and use its `is()` method:

```php
assert($request instanceof \Cake\Http\ServerRequest);
if (!$request->is('json')) {
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => [/* ...*/],
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);
}
```

Also note that the authentication component will by default require the identity to be present and throw an exception accordingly, you do not have to do that yourself.

Comment: `$isJsonRequest` is always `false`... When I debug `$request->getHeader('Accept')` it returns `["application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"]`. How can I check `application/json` in the request header ?

Comment: @Oliv I mistakenly assumed that the underlying request implementation would provide the accept header value already parsed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @ndm, now I don't have the redirection any more but the strange thing is that the `errorThrown` is now to `Unauthorized` instead of `Unauthenticated`...

Comment: @Oliv There is no `Unauthenticated` HTTP status message, only `Unauthorized`, which belongs to a 401 error, which is what the unauthenticated exception maps to.

Comment: Well...ok... The goal was to get an `UnauthenticatedException` more specific than `UnauthorizedException` especially to reload page in order to access to the login page... Too bad. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Oliv Unauthenticated and unauthorized are two different things. CakePHP's unauthorized exception maps to a 403 Forbidden error, so that's how you can distinguish them, 401 vs 403 status codes. Don't get confused about HTTP status messages, "401 Unauthorized" doesn't mean the same thing as not being authorized in the CakePHP application.

Comment: Thank you for the precision ndm. Now, I check the error code instead of `errorThrown`.